# Replace either string with another string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace `Hvos` or `Hc` with `Hdp`:

```
var hvos = "Dhhs.Hvos.Automation.UI";
var hc = "Dhhs.Hc.Automation.UI";
var pattern = "H(c|v)*(os)";
var replacement = "Hdp";
var str1 = Regex.Replace(hc, pattern, replacement).Replace("UI", "Data");
Console.WriteLine(str1);
var str2 = Regex.Replace(hvos, pattern, replacement).Replace("UI", "Data");
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

But only `Hvos` is replaced and `Hc` is not:

```
Dhhs.Hc.Automation.Data
Dhhs.Hdp.Automation.Data
```

`str1` and `str2` are expected to be the same.

Comment: Because (os) is not optional, but I think it's better to do a full "H((vos)|c)". (Not sure if that's fully correct.)

Comment: Why are you using REGEX for somthing so simple.  You can use String.Replace instead.  If you want str1 to equial str2 then just use str2 = str1;

Comment: Because in ".Hc." there is no OS , you are looking for Charaters optional `?`. For example `ab?c` will match abc or ac OR write your or the other way around (hvos|hc) h(vos|c)

Comment: @jdweng They are not called at the same time. `str1` and `str2` will not occur in the same place. This is just to simulate replacement.

Comment: string.Replace wouldnt work?

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks! It also worked when I placed the `*` _after_ `(os)` rather than before it. Your pattern is much more readable though. Happy to accept if you put as answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the pattern that you tried, this part `(c|v)*` matches 0+ times either `c` or `v` and could for example also match `ccc` or `cvvc`

You can write the pattern using a character class with an optional part to match `os`, and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial matches.

```
\bH[cv](?:os)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRdVyz/1)

**Note** that the pattern would also match `Hcos`

As pointed out in the comments by [JHBonarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6717178/jhbonarius), this pattern would be a more precise match:

```
\bH(?:c|vos)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B3hCi6/1)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand now the `*` needed to be after `(os)` than before it.

Comment: Note that if you just `(os)*` it can possibly also match `ososos`

Comment: Pretty sure the string will stay the same in this case but good point.

Answer (score -1):

Create one method that does this and call it for both values

string s = str.Replace("Hvos", "Hdp").Replace("Hc","Hdp");

Comment: i think he is trying to do something else